# Multilined Edittext

Tags: android, android-layout

I want a multilined `EditText`: when a new text is appended, the height of the `EditText` will change according to the length of the text and will not allow horizontal and vertical scroll.

Comment: could you please share what you have tried

Comment: i want to multiline edittext.

Comment: this is my layout file<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edProductDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:hint="@string/productdescription"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="4"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

Comment: android:lines="4" will restrict your edittext to be maximum 4 line long... remove this

Comment: I tried but its not work Ankit Bansal

Comment: i tried to show edittext same as textarea control how to do this...?

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText 
android:id="@+id/edProductDescription"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp" 
android:background="@color/white" 
android:hint="@string/productdescription"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:lines="4" 
android:padding="5dp"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"     
android:textColor="@color/black"
android:textStyle="bold" 
android:maxLines="100"
android:inputType="textMultiLine|textImeMultiLine"/>
```